# Vue.js - How to bind to form elements generated after page load?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, turbolinks, marketo

I have form elements aren't available in the html document until an inline script runs on page load. How to I bind to these form elements in Vue.js after the page loads? Obviously with jQuery I could do a `$('.element').each(),` but what is the 'Vue way'? I need to set the `value`attribute of the hidden inputs.

```html
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="AST_Goals__c" class="mktoField mktoFieldDescriptor mktoFormCol" value="" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="Perception_of_AppSec_program__c" class="mktoField mktoFieldDescriptor mktoFormCol" value="" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
</form>
```

Comment: Is the inline script independent of Vue? You could also just add the input fields with Vue (based on dynamic data).

Comment: Do you already have a Vue app on this page? Is this generated inside it?

Comment: You might want to read this, if the script is outside of Vue: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/mount-vue-instance-on-existing-html-element-while-keeping-child-nodes/33339/16

Comment: The script that generates the form is in the head of the document, and the form that gets generated from the script is nested in the Vue app container div.

Comment: I don't have control over the form elements. It is a form that gets embedded from a third party script. Like Hubspot or Marketo forms. These fields can be changed by the content editors.

Comment: I can move the script into Vue.js and generate it from there, if that is the best way? Just haven't been able to track down how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to call the `MktoForms2.loadForm()` function in the js file, not within `<script>` tags in the html file. You can't bind vue elements within inline `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need to access the DOM in this case...

Based on the Marketo [docs that show an example of setting a hidden field's value](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/assets/forms/examples/#crayon-6093189ec3c95809490677), you could use [`form.vals()`](https://developers.marketo.com/javascript-api/forms/api-reference/) in the `MktoForms2.loadForm()`'s callback:

```js
MktoForms2.loadForm('//app-ab00.marketo.com', '785-UHP-775', 1057, form => { 
  form.vals({
    AST_Goals__c: 'my goal',
    Perception_of_AppSec_program__c: 'my perception'
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks Tony. I had tried this. The problem was I was calling `MktoForms2.loadForm()`  in the html file, not in the vue file. Kinda dumb now that I think about it. Should have been clearer in my question so someone could have said "call the loadForm function in JS, not inline in the html." Your answer helped get me there.